# Python remainder operator using list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to use the remainder operator to find positive values in a list and print them as it finds them.

```
ExampleList=[2,5,-34,0,389,202,8]
```

I guess I don't understand how to make the operator use the list and then print the values.

Comment: Uhm, the remainder of what calculation, to be precise?

Comment: You don't need reminder operator you need `>`. And you can use it within a list comprehension. `[i for i in ExampleList if i>0]`

Comment: @Kasramvd, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Kevin we don't if that's the answer, because the question is unclear.

Comment: i guess that's where my issue is, "use % operator to find positive values", that's all the information i was given. using 2 would find even but not positives so i guess i don't have enough information to solve this.

Comment: @Kevin No It's just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sys
li = [2,5,-34,0,389,202,8]
m = sys.maxint
print [e for e in li if e == e%m]
```

Comment: sys.maxint was apparently changed to sys.maxsize in python 3.x, works great with that change thanks

Comment: @shadow: That's not actually a generally good result, because there is no actual maximum value of a Python 3 `int` (and in Py2, `int` seamlessly converts to `long`, which effectively means no limit). If the list contains `sys.maxsize` or any multiple thereof, this will fail. It's why [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35515094/364696) used squaring to produce a value with guaranteed larger magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

```
ExampleList=[2,5,-34,0,389,202,8]

for i in ExampleList:

    if ((i % 10) != (abs(i) % 10)):
        print (i)
```

The above code works for this particular example but might not work generally because there are numbers which no matter if they are positive or negative give the same modulus results.

Comment: Mind you, this doesn't do anything that `if i != abs(i):` wouldn't do. The `%` operation is completely superfluous.

Comment: i agree with you but op specifically asked how to determine if a number is negative or positive using the modulus operation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, any solution using `<` or related comparisons or `abs` isn't actually using any unique features of `%`. So just for fun, a kinda silly way to do it without using any special functions, and with no comparisons other than `==` that actually use a behavior of `%` in a meaningful way (as opposed to just adding `%` to code that would produce the correct result without it) for this purpose:

```
>>> li = [2,5,-34,0,389,202,8]
>>> print([x for x in li if x == x % (x ** 2 + 1)])
[2, 5, 0, 389, 202, 8]
```

We square `x` to create a value known to be larger than the absolute value of `x` (and add `1` to handle the special cases of `0` and `1`).

Another kind of tricky approach is to use the number as the divisor in such a way as to always get a fixed value from non-negative inputs:

```
# 1 % (x+2 or x+1) returns 1 for 0 or positive, non-1 for negative
# Use x+2 or x+1 to avoid ZeroDivisionError for x == 0
>>> print([x for x in li if 1 == 1 % (x+2 or x+1)])
[2, 5, 0, 389, 202, 8]

# We can even avoid using == by substituting subtraction since the result
# is a fixed 1 for non-negative, though it's pretty ugly looking
>>> print([x for x in li if not 1 % (x+2 or x+1) - 1])
[2, 5, 0, 389, 202, 8]

# Or if 0 shouldn't be included in results, tweak the divisor differently:
>>> print([x for x in li if 1 == 1 % (x+1 or x)])
[2, 5, 389, 202, 8]
```